# NGINX - simple reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

TLDR: I'm trying to reverse proxy a web-app through Nginx and it isn't passing through as it should.

**Nginx**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name dns.example.com;
    access_log logs/dns.access.log main;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        root /var/www/com.example.dns;
        proxy_pass http://192.168.1.30:5380;
    }
}
```

docker:  https://hub.docker.com/r/jpillora/dnsmasq/~/dockerfile/

appication: https://github.com/jpillora/webproc

if I connect directly (http://localnetwork.lan:5380) it works like a charm. If I connect via the reverse proxy (http://dns.example.com/) the images show up but not the active parts.

What am I missing? How can I proxy_pass the application through?

Comment: One of the HTTP endpoints is apparently a Websocket. You may need to configure nginx for that. Check the browser console to learn more about what is failing.

Answer (score 1):

Add an error_log directive so that nginx can tell you what is wrong.  Make sure the  ngx_http_proxy_module has been enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Daniels comment put me in the right direction: Websockets and "upgrade" to 1.1

https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/

```
location /wsapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://wsbackend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
}
```